# What kind of modifier are the two words “allurement and fulfillment” in the following extracted sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, subject-complement, post-modifier

- It is a challenge and a wonder, **an allurement and a fulfillment**, **which** man can never escape but has to encounter.

What type of modifier are these two words?

Are they referring back to the pronoun **it** or the two words “a challenge and a fulfillment”?

And what is **which** modifying here?

——-

[Source](http://www.advaita.org.uk/discourses/teachers/world_mishra.htm)

Comment: They all refer back to _it_. So does _which_. I think. It's not very clearly written.

Answer (score 1):

These words are [subject complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement) of the subject "it", which referees back to "nature" in the previous sentence (as it appears in the source).

The referenced text is written in a somewhat pompous style, and in my opinion it seems to be aimed at creating an impression rather than helping the reader understand the underlying message. So it's no wonder that it gives rise to such questions.